# Spotipy Getting songs of artists

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import json
token =util.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id, client_secret)
cache_token = token.get_access_token()
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)

tids = []
track_list = []
artist_list = ['Taylor Swift','Linkin Park','Charlie Puth']
for artist in artist_list:
 print artist
 results = spotify.search(q=artist,limit = 50)
 for i, t in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
  tids.append(t['uri'])
```

This gives me a an error like this :

SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - [Link](https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/?ids=4nVBt6MZDDP6tRVdQTgxJg,6tKW2g2So84pCTZXE0Furx,5O2P9iiztwhomNh8xkR9lJ,7kSLdGdXLey7pzLsWpdg1h,2K87XMYnUMqLcX3zvtAF4G,2afCBiru10AFckfOa49wIa,0HMjXBAZmSYOTTi33WpMso,72C7aUQECOhNtnD0AC36ua,3NLnwwAQbbFKcEcV8hDItk,3SPDQfj2UfWq6A2NllZnzn,2Bs4jQEGMycglOfWPBqrVG,5CRVwXGikmqzoRO6q7FeAg,5T7ZFtCcOgkpjxcuaeZbw0,3JjnGLK8IxkNLvo8Lb3KOM,0AkQbXGN4KG34TS7xLrM68,5omYVLodGmaxnhua99xIE8,48vlTTvosBO3rErgxYKxxR,4JaLkM90MJutDAl5jD9BZX,6nIE1oCE4udqMGv3bqVNVb,1ZWLWVqeEMWMKTlteS0yLH,1UAXlOxY1NXiJpP2sEK102,0L5gFNrzHyh4OhMwEz6DGS,6N5xh0tYYLTQRiCCaNbAUt,6aGjEZ7kq3YXgD0EDt80O5,34aYkYrY3sXhEU9O4VQgtB,6AzCBeiDuUXGXjznBufswB,6HFywc5eQYRRYHYTatCb5Y,4RC5YmcpCbRsX3AtRzoQeh,1dQQ2QlnvXUehsRUrukKmf,608R6FvRtAqf2dvgKMzebP,5AezhHjX3R1bmxcAEgrFpS,7pWzcvjSSXlGS0Cn790Nb7,5wjmqUGN7vrAqFqDWrywlZ,3cKM7UXBZmgjEgEBTkaIlU,03oZejWqXLbKhhM4iTgShq,4hJfmMjy3wFIOknfYwhouY,5Lf9rCqReE9Ri4tZvLRLuy,4RpsltwxERLiq6AXU39Dhx,0iSWAT0EL8TwmzcgBjKMh6,5dONhl6aXFuN86UBdayF6W,70OTIpw8x8UXUsuCHW9i1i,7rdP71W8x4UbJ0KAKBACbo,1BxXN8mBcTPhtuFLXD2dwH,7MbII8jWqFiTFYU3MPYEfW,5UgsZiYk1lkEobuPHmRtWm,6twW4ma6w0mOeejejPK0nY,3yAmqW5F28duOyV60VtIgN,7GtGeeChOx4NS77bqK8SUx,3UT493iwo6kvyL18zvAJE5,2Xcvt8NRLw0xbB3ClfW8MI,60a0Rd6pjrkxjPbaKzXjfq,2nLtzopw4rPReszdYBJU6h,18lR4BzEs7e3qzc0KVkTpU,3xXBsjrbG1xQIm1xv1cKOt,0UFDKFqW2oGspYeYqo9wjA,104buTcnP2AsxqB7U1FIZ4,3K4HG9evC7dg3N0R9cYqk4,7dyluIqv7QYVTXXZiMWPHW,57BrRMwf9LrcmuOsyGilwr,1Vej0qeQ3ioKwpI6FUbRv1,7oVEtyuv9NBmnytsCIsY5I,3FQCJI2t5LTbsRPfYVBSVB,7nAfXgeHfDO50upcOjJOaq,4HcDu9IGRCvSTJE4yW5Ugv,0sp00HSXkQyqTa6QqM0O8V,32bqxZEJRJObeNyc8bEiPt,1d5UuboIPRMD4HaU3yycKC,5sNESr6pQfIhL3krM8CtZn,2uxL6E8Yq0Psc1V9uBtC4F,1r1fPuhj9H4VdXr7OK6FL5,5rAxhWcgFng3s570sGO2F8,0OYcEfskah1egYHjYRvbg1,3BmjRmFTESgWZLPSVGp8aG,3dJj6o9o1fRgrojWjailuz,1fLlRApgzxWweF1JTf8yM5,0kO3njY9N1Rxgv27Ha1lLh,5egqKwgK5r5rvGD1LrtR7J,4Yf5bqU3NK4kNOypcrLYwU,650OeHTLxZAQmb4aEbGmaA,6Wx88Mv6b9ofjKMKkdwOJd,6c0I7CfL9ziGZN8yYkLppP,3agtg0x11wPvLIWkYR39nZ,34isqXjbTstbYwl2MfdzDq,6xtQ23d8GEXgcxyUKPtwc5,6OocN63GLU7NF0wHdewhID,5KNJ2qBD92lNfdcdcHmzEY,01pOtDU5YHWbxuNBzlRUem,2oNYsdCasRRlz1shXFAz7D,6n8TMVyFKoUmDc4apxceRD,1KvyBpAxgllKW7bQb0GYCR,27gUeiai56GKF6TxvmPJut,4CWhc9FaMMfBTt4ANjfbOf,3tSmXSxaAnU1EPGKa6NytH,0fxGA5lxrdYNYoE7yJxTNZ,5uuXtfqM7Wp3idCxyHeOll,5VYbLzAplnqPaGNpcf8qhZ,6UzeOH4bRPzKTo2wCXMZmC,2NXLCUySCK9odGGCGIzbOA,5x2Sk2NUsatM0kIh7boKwP,5Za8bsHPb08SZXm0bvbDXy,32DGGj6KlNuBr6WaqRxpxi,4iLqG9SeJSnt0cSPICSjxv,2JzZzZUQj3Qff7wapcbKjc,6GBMbvX7sqyOxT5wWK4hgN,37FXw5QGFN7uwwsLy8uAc0,7soJgKhQTO8hLP2JPRkL5O,0GOJobsbOSIF99y6CGr5o6,3qk4wRMDlaeagZGjSYbsOV,4mGXCXP9khO6DfRPI3vIuG,6ukMqDxnOPOgoHdak7Kyp3,2iLGgm4O5Hia8aSfSzXS3H,2nI6aT3cnPFoXQ1L705wcY,5uAeahijdsH6Pu4es1OVCt,52lFClZTgHPAhG8B7VXtFZ,7rdjfrTBMNt3KaaGvSv3YG,7rl1z4j7MurMDnn9rHh4M2,1RdykyqZss4snJH9e58CQJ,4dMvtp8p5mzCCaA18dgzQy,3GZ0dzX0472RyBKgnRGydA,4RcttSz7uRL9O2NyuFKaW2,4Ccmop9CkDfU6PWtvOEAbn,7uFhHMYpEC2MLXwxt64pMD,1tzY9nbWjQuFxu27rErzOf,2bKS7HtZ9Cy4K7NGeRlePF,4KVzPTFZXByIdBBH9dXiLT,4Aep3WGBQlpbKXkW7kfqcU,6qHPJleQOdQDEZvbxjY7jR,0DbVHIAldoWzrImJU9WN5y,4qE36yuwYbHnsPzlwhrO3M,19f9roe77Hen23e6vJ1iBN,1ldDywsJ7ke7JHe944EGfU,33SkruahtMKjSqtVQB9ryC,2xbrSRHA5mZdjmemo3bMZa,1KoSVcMX0QEQSvqxTemRnR,5T5X1awq0Tzg0NgQ4bSVAE,73E8dgeUdDu8iaZbQv1Fmk,6npLtUJC0l8WDKHPeP2rwX,2Y1LWNrO3Ls6tK9LZVehXk,1pak7n34ccFTxdNq3jDWFh,0pimOBUm2iDR5kv7Jw87U0,5VnyRoMMNbBIYiyE4jn5u4,1ZG8XKVPjKCHcL9Zmw5dXW,5vPTVMplZbchJBYDqOEDWc,2PpVX0Vu2j1mdeNueMDPZF,1UTlDJKLysbiFZO7phs9WV,6qgMSxNUPmqHbVr5uPKuqo,3qVZXhECuCCsPMm7toPO8X,4QArRxewE1TEJb8AiwfMYF,6BZo8QJr9A3nNFVU7WNjWN,6KYVdZ8ZGi0StyfyJ0Sinr:)

invalid request

Any idea why?

This is my first time posting to stackoverflow so pardon me if I've done any mistakes in the format of the post.

Comment: I didn't get such 400 code when I tried to execute your code. Maybe check your `client_id` and `client_secret` values? Worth checking if you get the same exception with a `curl` command to the search endpoint...

Comment: @DavidB. I tried it again but it shows the same error. The code seems to work fine when I change the limit from 50 to 10 or 20.